# Override Prestashop Module Changes not Visible

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I am attempting to override a module in Prestashop but the changes are just not appearing.

I have overridden a template file and a controller so I have added the following files:

> \override\modules\blockwishlist\views\templates\front\mywishlist.tpl
>   \override\modules\blockwishlist\controllers\front\mywishlist.php

These are very simple changes where I add another column to a table that contains a button. When the button is clicked the controller generates a CSV file.

Any idea why these changes are just not being shown?

Note: I have turned on 'Force Compile' and turned of caching.

**Edit**:
Re overridding a controller is it:

```
class BlockWishListMyWishListModuleFrontController extends BlockWishListMyWishListModuleFrontControllerCore // extends ModuleFrontController
```

or

```
class BlockWishListMyWishListModuleFrontControllerOverride extends BlockWishListMyWishListModuleFrontController
```

Answer (score 1):

okay, I did some code research (maybe thre is exists easiest way, not sure), so:

in code `Dispatcher` class we have

```
// Dispatch module controller for front office
            case self::FC_MODULE :
                $module_name = Validate::isModuleName(Tools::getValue('module')) ? Tools::getValue('module') : '';
                $module = Module::getInstanceByName($module_name);
                $controller_class = 'PageNotFoundController';
                if (Validate::isLoadedObject($module) && $module->active) {
                    $controllers = Dispatcher::getControllers(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$module_name.'/controllers/front/');
                    if (isset($controllers[strtolower($this->controller)])) {
                        include_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$module_name.'/controllers/front/'.$this->controller.'.php');
                        $controller_class = $module_name.$this->controller.'ModuleFrontController';
                    }
                }
                $params_hook_action_dispatcher = array('controller_type' => self::FC_FRONT, 'controller_class' => $controller_class, 'is_module' => 1);
            break;
```

where we see that controllers loaded without overrides, but from other side below in code we see hook execution:

```
// Loading controller
            $controller = Controller::getController($controller_class);

            // Execute hook dispatcher
            if (isset($params_hook_action_dispatcher)) {
                Hook::exec('actionDispatcher', $params_hook_action_dispatcher);
            }
```

so *one of possible solution* (without overriding core class) :

1. [how to override module](http://build.prestashop.com/howtos/module/how-to-override-modules/) and hope you have core version >= 1.6.0.11
2. in `blockwishlist.php` in `install()` method add

   `this->registerHook('actionDispatcher')`

to condition with other hooks, so it will looks like `... !this->registerHook('actionDispatcher') || ...` because this hook not registered by default and we can't just place module there.

3. create method (can't beautify code here)

   `public function hookActionDispatcher($params)
       {
           if ('blockwishlistmywishlistModuleFrontController' == $params['controller_class']) {
               include_once(_PS_OVERRIDE_DIR_ . 'modules/' . $this->name . '/controllers/front/mywishlist.php');
               $controller = Controller::getController('BlockWishListMyWishListModuleFrontControllerOverride');
           }
       }`
4. you already have `override/modules/blockwishlist/controllers/front/mywishlist.php` file by this path
5. reinstall module.
6. it works!

more about overriding some behaviors in [docs](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Overriding+default+behaviors)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it didn't work. I have made an edit to my question re overridding controllers which is the correct method?

Comment: Thanks for your edit. Do you think if I just place the controller class in the `~/overrides/modules/.....` directory that it will work - instead of having to do what you suggest?

Comment: you can try and will see result (I think - not)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that to override a module you dont place your files in:

> ~/overrides/module/MODULE_NAME

Instead you place it in:

> ~/themes/MY_THEME/modules/MODULE_NAME

Now the changes are exhibiting themselves.

*Does anyone know if/when the module is auto-updated, will my changes get lost/overrwritten?*

Comment: files in theme folder will not overrwritten on module update, but are you sure that controller class was overriden by placing mywishlist.php file there?