# Override Prestashop Module Controller: Where to place php file?

Tags: php, prestashop

I am attempting to override a module in Prestashop. I have successfully overridden the modules' templates but I cannot successfully overwrite the modules' controller.

Where should the new controller class file be placed?

I have tried the following locations but they dont add new behaviour (change anything):

> ~/overrides/modules/blockwishlist/controllers/front/mywishlist.php
>   ~/themes/MY_THEME/modules/blockwishlist/controllers/front/mywishlist.php

*According to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33726382/972202) I could do it by editing core classes (suggested kindly by u/Sergii P) but I am sure there is a standard way to do this that doesn't involve editing core classes?*

For reference; here is the contents of `mywishlist.php`:

```
<?php

if (!defined('_CAN_LOAD_FILES_'))
    exit;

//class BlockWishListMyWishListModuleFrontController extends BlockWishListMyWishListModuleFrontControllerCore // extends ModuleFrontController
class BlockWishListMyWishListModuleFrontControllerOverride extends BlockWishListMyWishListModuleFrontController
{

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * Assign wishlist template
     */
    public function assign()
    {
        $errors = array();

        ....

        $this->setTemplate('mywishlist.tpl');
    }

}
```

**EDIT:** I have a possible workaround for not being able to override the `ModuleFrontController` class. The objective is to add an 'Export to CSV' button to the My Wishlists page, when the button is clicked the server will generate a CSV file containing all products in that wishlist. Before I do all the work, can you provide advice on whether this is possible...

- Place hook in template file that will call a custom hook and be linked to a custom module `{hook h='displayExportToCsvColumn' mod='myCustomModule'}`
- Create a custom module that registers the new hook, has a method that renders the table column and button and has a method that generates the CSV file.
- Big Question: can you have a module inside a module? The template file I am editting is inside the module `BlockWishlist` (*~/themes/MY_THEME/modules/blockwishlist/controllers/front/mywishlist.php*) and then my hook will call my custom module. Is this possible?

Comment: It may depend on what PS version you have. Some overrides were only added in the recent versions.

Comment: @gskema Thanks for your comment. I have version 1.6.1.2. Where should the controller file be placed in this version of PS?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I could work out, you can't override `ModuleFrontController` at the moment (sorry to say). The clues lie within `Dispatcher::dispatch()`:

```
    case self::FC_MODULE :
        $module_name = Validate::isModuleName(Tools::getValue('module')) ? Tools::getValue('module') : '';
        $module = Module::getInstanceByName($module_name);
        $controller_class = 'PageNotFoundController';
        if (Validate::isLoadedObject($module) && $module->active) {
            $controllers = Dispatcher::getControllers(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$module_name.'/controllers/front/');
            if (isset($controllers[strtolower($this->controller)])) {
                include_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$module_name.'/controllers/front/'.$this->controller.'.php');
                $controller_class = $module_name.$this->controller.'ModuleFrontController';
            }
        }
        $params_hook_action_dispatcher = array('controller_type' => self::FC_FRONT, 'controller_class' => $controller_class, 'is_module' => 1);
    break;
```

It only checks the `/modules/?/controllers/` directory. You can't override the `ModuleFrontController` classes, but if you're smart enough, you can override `Dispatcher` class and make it scan for overrides of `ModuleFrontController`.

Usually there is a way to alter things you want with hooks, worst case scenario - inject javascript via hook and alter content.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I achieve the following using hooks...What I am trying to do is add a new column to the wishlists table. This column has a button 'Export to CSV'. So I'll need to postback to a PHP file to generate the csv file. Are hooks an option here?

Comment: I'm sorry to say I don't have much experience with wishlist module. If you mean a column in a HTML table, then yes, you could certainly do that with hooks, check whihc hooks are executed by doing `error_log($hook_name)` in `HookCore::exec`, choose a hook, make an `if` to target a specific page. To genearte the CSV you'll probably have to call your own PHP script

Answer (score 0):

Hey I've struggled with this issue aswell.
I ended up spotting a solution on the prestashop forums : 
https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/480523-override-front-controller-of-modules/

The user Alex has created a override for the Dispatcher that will check for any module controller overrides.

The file does not seem to be available on the forum anymore you can however still find it here along with some explanations on how it works :
http://nemops.com/overriding-modules-controllers-in-prestashop-1-6/#.XDR7HHX0muU

In case none of those work anymore here is the code :

```
    <?php

if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_')) {
    exit;
}

class Dispatcher extends DispatcherCore
{

    public function dispatch()
    {
        $controller_class = '';

        // Get current controller
        $this->getController();
        if (!$this->controller) {
            $this->controller = $this->useDefaultController();
        }
        // Dispatch with right front controller
        switch ($this->front_controller) {
            // Dispatch front office controller
            case self::FC_FRONT :
                $controllers = Dispatcher::getControllers(
                    array(_PS_FRONT_CONTROLLER_DIR_, _PS_OVERRIDE_DIR_.'controllers/front/')
                );
                $controllers['index'] = 'IndexController';
                if (isset($controllers['auth'])) {
                    $controllers['authentication'] = $controllers['auth'];
                }
                if (isset($controllers['compare'])) {
                    $controllers['productscomparison'] = $controllers['compare'];
                }
                if (isset($controllers['contact'])) {
                    $controllers['contactform'] = $controllers['contact'];
                }

                if (!isset($controllers[strtolower($this->controller)])) {
                    $this->controller = $this->controller_not_found;
                }
                $controller_class = $controllers[strtolower($this->controller)];
                $params_hook_action_dispatcher = array(
                    'controller_type' => self::FC_FRONT,
                    'controller_class' => $controller_class,
                    'is_module' => 0,
                );
                break;

            // Dispatch module controller for front office
            case self::FC_MODULE :
                $module_name = Validate::isModuleName(Tools::getValue('module')) ? Tools::getValue('module') : '';
                $module = Module::getInstanceByName($module_name);
                $controller_class = 'PageNotFoundController';
                if (Validate::isLoadedObject($module) && $module->active) {
                    $controllers = Dispatcher::getControllers(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$module_name.'/controllers/front/');

                    if (isset($controllers[strtolower($this->controller)])) {
                        include_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$module_name.'/controllers/front/'.$this->controller.'.php');

                        if (file_exists(
                            _PS_OVERRIDE_DIR_.'modules/'.$module_name.'/controllers/front/'.$this->controller.'.php'
                        )) {
                            include_once(_PS_OVERRIDE_DIR_.'modules/'.$module_name.'/controllers/front/'.$this->controller.'.php');
                            $controller_class = $module_name.$this->controller.'ModuleFrontControllerOverride';
                        } else {

                            $controller_class = $module_name.$this->controller.'ModuleFrontController';
                        }
                    }
                }
                $params_hook_action_dispatcher = array(
                    'controller_type' => self::FC_FRONT,
                    'controller_class' => $controller_class,
                    'is_module' => 1,
                );
                break;

            // Dispatch back office controller + module back office controller
            case self::FC_ADMIN :
                if ($this->use_default_controller && !Tools::getValue('token') && Validate::isLoadedObject(
                        Context::getContext()->employee
                    ) && Context::getContext()->employee->isLoggedBack()) {
                    Tools::redirectAdmin(
                        'index.php?controller='.$this->controller.'&token='.Tools::getAdminTokenLite($this->controller)
                    );
                }

                $tab = Tab::getInstanceFromClassName($this->controller, Configuration::get('PS_LANG_DEFAULT'));
                $retrocompatibility_admin_tab = null;

                if ($tab->module) {
                    if (file_exists(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$tab->module.'/'.$tab->class_name.'.php')) {
                        $retrocompatibility_admin_tab = _PS_MODULE_DIR_.$tab->module.'/'.$tab->class_name.'.php';
                    } else {
                        $controllers = Dispatcher::getControllers(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$tab->module.'/controllers/admin/');
                        if (!isset($controllers[strtolower($this->controller)])) {
                            $this->controller = $this->controller_not_found;
                            $controller_class = 'AdminNotFoundController';
                        } else {
                            // Controllers in modules can be named AdminXXX.php or AdminXXXController.php
                            include_once(_PS_MODULE_DIR_.$tab->module.'/controllers/admin/'.$controllers[strtolower(
                                    $this->controller
                                )].'.php');
                            $controller_class = $controllers[strtolower($this->controller)].(strpos(
                                    $controllers[strtolower($this->controller)],
                                    'Controller'
                                ) ? '' : 'Controller');
                        }
                    }
                    $params_hook_action_dispatcher = array(
                        'controller_type' => self::FC_ADMIN,
                        'controller_class' => $controller_class,
                        'is_module' => 1,
                    );
                } else {
                    $controllers = Dispatcher::getControllers(
                        array(
                            _PS_ADMIN_DIR_.'/tabs/',
                            _PS_ADMIN_CONTROLLER_DIR_,
                            _PS_OVERRIDE_DIR_.'controllers/admin/',
                        )
                    );
                    if (!isset($controllers[strtolower($this->controller)])) {
                        // If this is a parent tab, load the first child
                        if (Validate::isLoadedObject($tab) && $tab->id_parent == 0 && ($tabs = Tab::getTabs(
                                Context::getContext()->language->id,
                                $tab->id
                            )) && isset($tabs[0])) {
                            Tools::redirectAdmin(Context::getContext()->link->getAdminLink($tabs[0]['class_name']));
                        }
                        $this->controller = $this->controller_not_found;
                    }

                    $controller_class = $controllers[strtolower($this->controller)];
                    $params_hook_action_dispatcher = array(
                        'controller_type' => self::FC_ADMIN,
                        'controller_class' => $controller_class,
                        'is_module' => 0,
                    );

                    if (file_exists(_PS_ADMIN_DIR_.'/tabs/'.$controller_class.'.php')) {
                        $retrocompatibility_admin_tab = _PS_ADMIN_DIR_.'/tabs/'.$controller_class.'.php';
                    }
                }

                // @retrocompatibility with admin/tabs/ old system
                if ($retrocompatibility_admin_tab) {
                    include_once($retrocompatibility_admin_tab);
                    include_once(_PS_ADMIN_DIR_.'/functions.php');
                    runAdminTab($this->controller, !empty($_REQUEST['ajaxMode']));

                    return;
                }
                break;

            default :
                throw new PrestaShopException('Bad front controller chosen');
        }

        // Instantiate controller
        try {
            // Loading controller
            $controller = Controller::getController($controller_class);

            // Execute hook dispatcher
            if (isset($params_hook_action_dispatcher)) {
                Hook::exec('actionDispatcher', $params_hook_action_dispatcher);
            }

            // Running controller
            $controller->run();
        } catch (PrestaShopException $e) {
            $e->displayMessage();
        }
    }

}
```

- Add this file to override/classes directory
- Delete the cache/class_index.php file

After this it is possible to override module controllers by putting the override file in :

`override/modules/{moduleName}/controllers/{front/admin}/{filename}.php`

In this file you have to define a class with the exact same name as the class you want to override and append "Override" at the end of the classname.

I hope this helps